# hoisting anonymous function expression which is an array item

Tags: javascript

This code needs to declare a function (preferably anonymous) inside the array
`({argObj}) => {console.log(`start`);}`
and define it later outside the `request = (function() {...}());` IIF.

```
request = (function () {
  const pathAfter = {
    start: ['homePage', 'GET', ({argObj}) => {console.log(`start`);}]
  };
  return {

    go: (argObj) => {
      if(!pathAfter[argObj.pathAfter]) return;

      const path = pathAfter[argObj.pathAfter][0];
      const method = pathAfter[argObj.pathAfter][1];
      const url = data.domain + path + data.ext;

      HTTP.call(method, url, (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log('error '+error);
        } else {
          pathAfter[path][2]({response: response}); // <---- calls relevant method

          request.go({pathAfter: path});
        }
      });
      return true; // if rms seccessful
    }
  };

}());

// function definition goes here...
```

I am not sure how to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely clear on what you are trying to acheive and how strict the requirements are, but one option might be to give the request object the ability to add/extend the *handlers* in `pathAfter`:

```
request = (function () {
    const pathAfter = {
        start: ['homePage', 'GET', ({argObj}) => {console.log('start');}]
    };
    return {

        go: (argObj) => {
            if(!pathAfter[argObj.pathAfter]) return;

            const path = pathAfter[argObj.pathAfter][0];
            const method = pathAfter[argObj.pathAfter][1];
            const url = data.domain + path + data.ext;

            HTTP.call(method, url, (error, response) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('error '+error);
                } else {
                    pathAfter[path][2]({response: response}); // <---- calls relevant method

                    request.go({pathAfter: path});
                }
            });
            return true; // if rms seccessful
        },

        registerPathHandler: (handlerName,handler)=> {
            pathAfter[handlerName] = handler;
        }

    };

}());

request.registerPathHandler('test', ['testPage', 'GET', ({argObj}) => {console.log('test');}]);
```

This will add a named handler, and could be used to add the `start` handler as well. If the start handler really needs to be hard-coded inside, then the code above could be modified to just replace the array element instead.